# how to remove clients with semp in solace

Tags: solace

How remove client by semp in solace.I try it like follows:

```
<rpc xmlns="http://www.solacesystems.com/semp/topic_routing/d35m1">
<no><client-username><username>user1</username>    
<vpn-name>jiavpn</vpn-name>   </client-username></no></rpc>
```

but it alert me "Command is not allowed via SEMP over the message bus",
did it have some relation with the SEMP TOPIC,my topic is #SEMP/soalce1/SHOW.
thanks for answer

Comment: You can use SEMP over HTTP. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878813/how-do-i-programmatically-disconnect-clients-which-are-connected-to-solace-appli/36907954?noredirect=1#comment61588750_36907954)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer is invalid.**
There is an error with the documentation which will be fixed in the next major release.

---

The disconnect SEMP over message bus command is an `Client Admin EXEC command`, and needs to be sent to `#SEMP/<router name>/ADMIN/CLIENT` instead of `#SEMP/<router name>/SHOW`.

From the [user guide](https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Message_Bus_and_Events_Management/Using_SEMP_to_Manage_and_Monitor_Routers.html#ww339516),

```
• Client Admin EXEC commands—These commands enable applications to clear and reset the given client’s event notification for a specified one-shot event or to disconnect the client. The following client admin EXEC commands can be executed over the message bus:
- admin client <name> message-vpn <vpn-name> [primary][backup] [static] clear-event <event-name>
- admin client <name> message-vpn <vpn-name> [primary][backup] disconnect

...

• #SEMP/<router name>/ADMIN/CLIENT—The command topic destination for Client Admin EXEC commands, which enable applications to clear and reset the given client’s event notification for a specified one-shot event or to disconnect the client.
```

Note that you will need to enable Admin and Client SEMP over Message Bus Commands for the message VPN. Refer to the screenshot below for an example of how to do this.

[image: Enable Admin and Client Commands]

Also note that the client application might be configured to automatically reconnect after a disconnect.

Comment: I have chang the Topic to "#SEMP/solace1/ADMIN/CLIENT", the semp xml is "<rpc semp-version="soltr/7_1_1"><admin><client><name>jiajie</name><vpn-name>jiajievpn</vpn-name><disconnect/></client></admin></rpc>", and enable semp over msg bus throught Soladmin ,but it still inform  me  "<permission-error>Command is not allowed via SEMP over the message bus</permission-error>".Do you have possible reason .thanks for answering.

Comment: It is likely that you've not enabled Admin and Client Commands for SEMP over Message Bus. I've edited my answer to include a screenshot of how to do so.

Comment: Thank you first.actually，I have set manage msg vpn like your screenshoot,but it still alert me <permission-error>Command is not allowed via SEMP over the message bus</permission-error>.Is any possibility that  the user don't have  Enough authority or others.

Comment: Can you clarify what is your SEMP command? `no client-username...` as per your modified OP, or `disconnect client...` as per your comment?

Comment: -1 down vote accept
 

I encounter the same problem too. My program login to a Management VPN which has the following setting:

<rpc semp-version="soltr/5_1">
  <admin>
    <client>
      <name>#client</name>
      <vpn-name>myvpn1</vpn-name>
      <disconnect/>
    </client>
  </admin>
</rpc>
myvpn1 is also having the same settings are shown in the image above. I am getting the same error too, as shown below.

<rpc-reply semp-version="soltr/7_1_1">
<permission-error>Command is not allowed via SEMP over the message bus</permission-error>
</rpc-reply>
Not sure what have I missed.

Comment: I can show client information throught semp,but can not disconnect the clients,it will alert"<permission-error>Command is not allowed via SEMP over the message bus</permission-error>".what is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following are SEMP commands that cannot be executed over the message bus.

Deleting a client-username:

```
<rpc xmlns="http://www.solacesystems.com/semp/topic_routing/d35m1">
    <no>
        <client-username>
            <username>user1</username>    
            <vpn-name>jiavpn</vpn-name>   
        </client-username>
    </no>
</rpc>
```

Disconnecting a client:

```
<rpc semp-version="soltr/7_1_1">
    <admin>
        <client>
           <name>jiajie</name>
           <vpn-name>jiajievpn‌​</vpn-name>
           <disconnect/>
        </client>
   </admin>
</rpc>
```

Only a limited subset of commands are available for SEMP over message bus.
The complete list can be found in [Available SEMP Over Message Bus Commands](https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Message_Bus_and_Events_Management/Using_SEMP_to_Manage_and_Monitor_Routers.html#ww339516).
Note that there is currently an error in the documentation that will be fixed in the next major release - Disconnecting clients are not allowed via message bus despite the documentation saying so.

Comment: That's bad news.Do you know  how to disconnect the clients by Java Program.