# How do I programmatically disconnect clients which are connected to Solace appliance?

Tags: solace

As Solace does not support deleting and disconnecting client via SEMP over a message bus, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759396/how-to-remove-clients-with-semp-in-solace), may I know how do I do that programmatically? I need to manage clients, especially client connection from my application.  Can I run trigger CLI scripts from my program to achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnecting a client is an administrative action that can only be executed by management users over the management interface. Client applications are not allowed to execute this action.

To disconnect a client, you can send a SEMP command through the management interface using a management user. (Not via SEMP over Message Bus.)

Comment: Appreciate it if you can share how to do what you have suggested, i.e. what do I use to send the SEMP command.  Is there any documentation on the steps?  Thank you!

Comment: Is it through SEMP over HTTP?

Comment: Yes, use SEMP over HTTP.